# rank by partition - reduce cost

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, window-functions, query-performance

I have a table as staging_data and I am trying to rank the data by the following query

```
UPDATE staging_data
SET rank = r.rnk
FROM (
    SELECT custtripid, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY vehiclenumber ORDER BY transactiondate asc) as rnk
    FROM staging_data
    ) r where staging_data.custtripid = r.custtripid;
```

the query is running continuously without giving any result. I tried running the sub-query and it's getting computed in a few seconds. Please suggest a way forward.

Edit -----
estimated execution plan:

```
Update on staging_data  (cost=899520.15..1805509.17 rows=3631528 width=776)
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=899520.15..1805509.17 rows=3631528 width=776)
        Hash Cond: ((staging_data.custtripid)::text = (r.custtripid)::text)
        ->  Seq Scan on staging_data  (cost=0.00..136700.28 rows=3631528 width=726)
        ->  Hash  (cost=815115.05..815115.05 rows=3631528 width=60)
              ->  Subquery Scan on r  (cost=706169.21..815115.05 rows=3631528 width=60)
                    ->  WindowAgg  (cost=706169.21..778799.77 rows=3631528 width=28)
                          ->  Sort  (cost=706169.21..715248.03 rows=3631528 width=28)
"                                Sort Key: staging_data_1.vehiclenumber, staging_data_1.transactiondate"
                                ->  Seq Scan on staging_data staging_data_1  (cost=0.00..136700.28 rows=3631528 width=28)
```

Comment: What is the table size in rows and in MB  ? What is the estimated execution plan (output of `EXPLAIN <your query>`) ?

Comment: table size: 1283 mb

Comment: The table is not very large but you are updating all rows which has always some cost in any database and maybe more in PG (as practically this means doubling physical table size due to MVCC implementation). Not sure there is an easy way to optimize this. In some cases, recreating the table with CREATE TABLE AS SELECT (and recreating indexes and constraints) could be faster but this mean downtime for the table.

Comment: Note also that each updated row will be locked with an exclusive lock.  You could also check with `pg_stat_activity` and `pg_locks` that there is no waiting lock.

Comment: Please show us the EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) for just the select portion of your update.  Also, what is the longest amount of time you waited for the UPDATE to complete before interupting it?